# Player stuttering while moving - Sprite Kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift4

My player is a `SKSpriteNode`. I am moving it with `CGVectors` and `player.physicsBody!.applyImpulse()`. This works fine, but as my player is moving, it seems to be stuttering to the left and right a lot. So to fix this, I tried changing some of the `physicsBody` properties. In the `update` function, I added this line of code: `player.physicsBody?.friction = 0`. This still changed nothing. So I thought that this stuttering was caused by the player touching the ground. So I added a new line of code in the update function: `player.position.y += 1`. Of course, due to the nature of this solution, the player now stuttered up and down, but was able to move left and right without a problem. This shows me that the problem is with some type of force when the player is touching the ground. How do I stop the player from stuttering?

Edit: I think it would be beneficial to also know that my "ground" is actually a bunch of `SKSpriteNode` put next to each other in a row to make it look like a tilemap.

Edit: My player's physics Body was setup using this line of code: `player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: player.size)`

Comment: Define “stutter”. Sounds like there is something se wrong with your code

Comment: Shifting left and right randomly while moving.

Comment: Ok well you will need to create an mcve to determine what is truly wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to the stuttering, and it was to simply change this line of code: `player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: player.size)` to a circle. By setting up the physicsBody as a circle, all stuttering is gone, but now I can't get the effect of my player standing on the ground.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using too many spritenodes try using SKTileMapNode. Will help you dramatically in terms of performance. There are tutorials on youtube and raywenderlich how to use them. Just watch and you’ll see it is quite simple to use

Comment: So the problem is not related to the player's physics at all?

Comment: I dont think do you have debug info enabled to see how many nodes you have on screen and the fps?

Comment: I am getting about 50 to 60 fps, and I cant use the `SKTileMapNode` because I am using custom classes for my ground.

Comment: Actually, I am getting a full 59 to 60 fps and the node count is 384

Comment: Are you running it in the simulator??

Comment: The app is actually for Mac Osx and not Iphone, I should have probably mentioned that.

Comment: If yes try physical device I remember when I ran a simple game a made in the simulator I had some problems with the image occasionally jumping but on the physical device it was ok

Comment: Oh ok. Dont know then perhaps build and run on the mac directly

Comment: That is how it works for mac apps, the target shows "My Mac".

Comment: See my answer below, I did manage to fix it. It wasn't related to the NodeCount it looks like.